# Is profoundly used correctly in the following sentence?

Tags: word-usage

Is "profoundly" used correctly in the following sentence?

> Social exclusion exerts a profoundly harmful effect on former
> prisoners and hinders them from re-entering society after release from
> prison.

I mean, is it natural to say that a harm is profound?

Comment: Have you looked this up? "profoundly harmful" + [nouns]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds natural enough to me, a native English speaker from the western US.